# Removing Windows - a safe procedure

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, removing

I'm finally ready to completely switch to Ubuntu a and remove my Windows partition.

Ubuntu is installed in its own primary partition, so it should be pretty easy, but I'd like to make sure not to run into troubles or have solutions ready, at least.

The partitions look like this:

[image: /dev/sda on my laptop]

**My plan**

Boot a Live Ubuntu from USB (no cd reader available!), delete /dev/sda3 and sda4, extend sda8 to the left

Then probably chmount in the existing Ubuntu installation and reinstall grub, just to make sure the machine will boot afterwards

Finally, follow the "Further Operation" steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows

**My doubts**

1. What is /dev/sda3, actually? Is it safe to remove?
2. Will I actually need to reinstall grub? Is it safe enough to do it regardless of the answer? (I did it 2 weeks ago successfully, because I first had to resize the partitions to have space in Ubuntu for a Win virtual machine...)
3. /dev/sda1 is the Windows Recovery Environment. I suppose I'd leave it there, together with /dev/sda5 and sda6, to make sure I can install a clean and working system at any moment, in case something went very wrong at any point in time (I prefer being conservative, as I need Windows for working - virtualized in VirtualBox, from now on). Does this make sense? Meaning, will it work, or I might be saving unusable partitions?
4. Am I forgetting or underestimating something?

I hope I'm not replicating the previous discussions on the subject: I didn't feel sure after reading through them, yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have thought out your operation clearly in advance and have tested most of the steps, and it looks correct. So, onto your doubts:

1. sda3 is Microsoft Reserved Partition. It is not used by Linux, and mostly used only by Windows (basically on first boot) for doing things that earlier (on MBR) disks were done by hidden disks. Windows requires it to be exactly AFTER EFI partition, and BEFORE Windows OS partition. DON'T NUKE THIS PARTITION.

This complicates things for you, for in future if you want to install Windows, it will fail unless you have >= 128MB unallocated free space (or a MSFT Reserve Partition) available exactly next to EFI. So, my advice, leave it there. Windows will need it for later Windows install.

2. Yes. Actually, you have a misconception here. You can't extend your partitions  to the left (which is what you are doing essentially). You MOVE your existing partition to left, to the place you want it to be, and AFTER that extend the partition to the right. This bit is complicated, and read up on parted move partition to left. After this, you run resize2fs to extend the filesystem to fill the partition.

So, three steps:

- Move partition to left
- Expand partition to right
- Resize file system to fill the new expanded partition

Remember, partition is different from the filesystem occupying it.

3. Nuke 1,5,6 to your heart's content. They are useless and a new Windows Install can anyways remake the ones you ACTUALLY need. Feel free to nuke them.
4. If you are planning (even if later) of actually installing Windows to this disk, it would be sensible to save the Windows Product Key (for activation).

Generally, Windows Key is saved (on Windows 8 and above laptops) in the BIOS, so windows generally shouldn't need it while installing Windows (it can get it directly, along with the manufacturer and their logo), but still, keeping the key is useful if you are planning some upgrades later.

Comment: It may be needed for re-installing an existing Windows10  as a client in Virtualbox as it appears there my be issues. A web search turned up some.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
Further questions/comments;
2. Yes, I did know that "extending to the left" is actually more complicated, but Gparted can handle it all automatically. When you resize a partition, you can choose either direction, and it will take care of just extending partition and fs (right) or moving and then extending (left).
3. I was thinking of leaving 1,5,6 because 6 is the Windows Recovery and I suppose 1 and 5 are needed for it to work/start. Without the recovery partition, I'd necessarily need an external drive to reinstall Windows, which I'd avoid
4. done already :)

Comment: @poomerang You are correct in your thinking. I don't reinstall from Recovery, as it had a lot of bloatware, I just download from Windows the iso and then burn and install it. Cleaner install that way, so it didn't occur to me that you might try that way. In that case, keep 3 as well, it is actually needed. 1, 5  are there because of Lenovo, Windows only needs: EFI (2) ,System (3), Windows OS partition (4), Recovery (6). So nuke 4 with impunity, keep 2,3 atleast.

Comment: @jpezz Interesting. I didn't know about that. However, since this is a Windows 8 install, so it didn't cross my mind to check that.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good suggestion to use the iso indeed, and I did create one through the Windows tool. But for the moment I prefer to have a working recovery in the internal sdd, as any external support can easily be lost or far from me, and I might need immediate action. I can always delete those partitions later :)

Comment: Just as a follow-up: the operation was successful! I decided to delete only sda4 for now, to make sure the Lenovo recovery can safely run at any time, knowing that I can always remove it to gain its (little) extra space.
Thank you all.